# Difference between string.GetHashCode and IEqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to use `Distinct()` with my data, declared as `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<IdentType, string>>`. In this case, i have to implement my own `IEqualityComparer` and there is my question:

Is there any difference between below implementations?

```
public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<IdentType, string> obj) {
    return EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(obj.Value);
}
```

and

```
public int GetHashCode(KeyValuePair<IdentType, string> obj) {
    return obj.Value.GetHashCode();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

There is only a small difference between your two methods.

[`EqualityComparer<string>.Default`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/910b559cdb8bd73e.html) will return a class of type [`GenericEqualityComparer<T>`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/mscorlib/R/e59de2b23f38e633.html) if the class implments `IEquateable<T>` (which string does). So that `GetHashCode(obj.Value)` gets called to

```
    public override int GetHashCode(T obj) {
        if (obj == null) return 0;
        return obj.GetHashCode();
    }
```

which is the same as you calling `obj.Value.GetHashCode();` directly, except for the fact that if you have a null string the default comparer will return 0 and the direct call version will throw a null reference exception.

Answer (score 3):

Just one: the equality comparer's `GetHashCode` will return 0 if the string is null, whereas the second implementation will throw an exception.

Answer (score 2):

One difference is that `EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode` would not crash when you pass `null` to it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var n = EqualityComparer<string>.Default.GetHashCode(null);
        Console.WriteLine(n);
    }
}
```

Other than that, the results would be identical by design, because `System.String` implements `IEquatable<System.String>`

> The Default property checks whether type T implements the `System.IEquatable<T>` generic interface and, if so, returns an `EqualityComparer<T>` that invokes the implementation of the `IEquatable<T>.Equals` method. Otherwise, it returns an `EqualityComparer<T>`, as provided by `T`.

Answer (score 1):

No. It doesn't. The implementation will be the same since they both call `GetHashCode()` on the actual class, in this case `string`.

In the end, the [`CreateComparer`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs#48) method inside the `EqualityComparer` [creates](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs#58) an [`GenericEqualityComparer`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs#117), and the implementation of it's [`GetHashCode`](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/equalitycomparer.cs#133) is:

```
public override int GetHashCode(T obj) {
    if (obj == null) return 0;
    return obj.GetHashCode();
}
```

In this case, `obj` will be the original `string` where you would otherwise call `GetHasCode` on. The only case that will make it behave differently is when your `string` is `null`.